# How to recreate built-in CommandBarPopup in Access for Runtime

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

currently I'm developing an application with Access 2013/2016. This software  should be runnable on client machines with the Access RUNTIME engine only. Now i noticed that all Ribbons/Context Menus are deactivated in RUNTIME mode.

Now I'm trying to create the necessary context menus by myself. This [article](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/12904/Understanding-and-using-CommandBars-Part-II-Creating-your-own.html) helped a lot, but I have a problem with CommandBarPopups.

I'm  trying to create the same context menu, that you can see in table cells/input fields on forms. In that, there is a very nice filter button/popup, which consider the underlying data type of the clicked cell. For Date types it shows "Date Filters", for Text types "Text Filters" and so on...

I found the internal control Id of this menu item (31581), but it doesn't show all the related sub-menu items of CommandBarPop. Then I tryied to include this sub-items manually, but then it will be shown all the sub-items all the time. The standard context menu is clever enough, to hide all unrelated sub-items (e.g. for Text types all the Date menus like Next Month, etc... )

This is my code until now. The commented lines are my problem.

```vb
Public Function CreateShortcutMenus()

On Error Resume Next
CommandBars("cmdFormFiltering").Delete
On Error GoTo 0


' Create the shortcut menu.
Dim cmdFormFiltering As Office.CommandBar
Set cmdFormFiltering = CommandBars.Add("cmdFormFiltering", msoBarPopup, False, True)

With cmdFormFiltering
    ' Add the Find command.
    .Controls.Add msoControlButton, 141, , , True

    ' Start a new grouping and add the Sort Ascending command.
    .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 210, , , True).BeginGroup = True

    ' Add the Sort Descending command.
    .Controls.Add msoControlButton, 211, , , True

    ' Start a new grouping and add the Remove Filer/Sort command.
    .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 605, , , True).BeginGroup = True

    ' Add the Filter FilterBySelection
    .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 640, , , True).BeginGroup = False

    Dim popUpFilter As Office.CommandBarPopup
    Set popUpFilter = .Controls.Add(msoControlPopup, 31581, , , True)
    popUpFilter.BeginGroup = True

' popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10077, , , True).BeginGroup = False
' popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10078, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10079, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 12696, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10080, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10081, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10088, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 12697, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 12698, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 12699, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10082, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10083, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10062, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10063, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10064, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10065, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 16206, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10067, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10066, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10058, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10069, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10070, , , True).BeginGroup = False
'        popUpFilter.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10059, , , True).BeginGroup = False

    ' Add the Filter FilterEqualsSelection
    .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 10068, , , True).BeginGroup = True

    ' Add the Filter FilterNotEqualsSelection
    .Controls.Add msoControlButton, 10071, , , True


End With

Set cmdFormFiltering = Nothing

End Function
```

What have I todo, that automatically all sub-items will be shown with control id 31581?

Regards,
Daniel